# Bi-Endian Compiler for ARM

Tags: gcc

Is there a Bi-Endian Compiler available for ARM ?

For my application running over Linux, I want part of the code to interact directly with Linux and hence LE and part of the code is BE.
To glue this code, I was able to use Intel Bi-Endian Compiler with wrappers when I run it over a Linux on Intel.
Is it possible to do the same with the help of gcc for ARM Linux too ?
I simply tried a test program with one file compiled with -mbig-endian and the other compiled with -mlittle-endian and when I try to link them, it throws an error!

Provided Bi-Endian GCC compiler for ARM is not available, is there an alternate option available to link different endian compiled code together ?

Comment: Related, see [GCC ARM Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html).